# ClosedXml, DocumentFormat.OpenExcel, ExcelNumberFormat, and FastMember

Tags: .net-assembly, compatibility, closedxml

The latest version of these four assemblies are as follows:

- Assembly-----------------------------Version
- ClosedXml ---------------------------- v0.91.0
- DocumentFormat.OpenExcel ---- v2.81
- ExcelNumberFormat---------------- v1.0.3
- FastMember --------------------------   v1.3.0

Unfortunately, they do not work with one another when deployed to another machine and running within a service application.  The ClosedXml seems to have a dependency on DocumentFormat.OpenExcel ver2.7.2, and FastMember 1.0.0.9

What is the latest working versions of these files that are compatible with one another?

Answer (score 0):

I also have found this out it throws an exception in my case 
StackTrace = "   en System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()\r\n   en System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n   en ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheet.Range(String rangeAddressStr)\r\n   en ClosedXML.Excel.XLPrintAreas.Add(String rangeAddress)\r\n  ...

was working fine before the upgrade